# getting error: compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported in android studio, how to fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio

i have recently upgraded my project to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
```

and for

```
compileSdkVersion 33
targetSdkVersion 33
```

ever since then i'm heaving build issues, with general building error
the current after adding every flag i could think about is saying

```
consumer-lib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported
```

i tried invalidating cash and restart, cleaning the project
and every other idea i could think about

is there anything else i could try to resolve this ?
do you know what went wrong there better ?

Comment: The tensorflow project identified android studio gradle plugin version as relevant when they had a similar issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/55485#issuecomment-1097311224 I would not have expected the studio version to be relevant if you have gradle, compile, and target set. But perhaps this gives you a lead to try. I wasn't able to see what the relevant change was, but perhaps different handling of generatedSourceOutputDirectory

Comment: Did you try changing the AGP version as well?

Comment: @Cadmium give any answer, i will give you the bounty. 
you have the least points and wanted to help me, you more then deserve them.

Comment: Please try to clean and rebuild,I think maybe some dependency jars has outdated
and java version also

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade `buildToolsVersion` to `"33.0.1"`.
Also as of now I prefer using
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip`.

Comment: tried both, still getting the same error of
compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50586433/10147641 - Please check this.

Comment: I dont get Any java compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

As a lead for further investigation, the common link on other threads on this error message seems to be version incompatibility:
example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68089083/7632432
or
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/55485#issuecomment-1097311224

It seems like you have set the versions explicitly to a supported configuration, but would be tempted to recreate the project (sounds like you may have done this) or experiment with changing the versions slightly to try to get a different output.